Jupyter Notebook Cannot Find Conda Commands in Environment
I'm having issues running conda commands within Jupyter Notebook while using my learning_jupyter environment. I can't run shell commands such as !pip install sympy or !which python in my local Jupyter Notebook environment. These commands work perfectly fine when I use Anaconda Cloud Notebooks, but not on my local machine.
Here's a summary of what I've tried and the errors I'm encountering.
Environment Details

Operating System: macOS
Anaconda Version: conda 24.7.1
Python Version: Python 3.12.2 (this is the same version used by my conda environment once activated)
I'm using zsh as my shell on macOS.
I have Anaconda installed and am working inside a Conda environment.
conda commands work fine in my terminal.

I've ensured that the Python interpreter in Jupyter Notebook is the same as the one used by Anaconda (/opt/anaconda3/envs/learning_jupyter/bin/python).
I've tried:

Reinstalling ipykernel and setting up a kernel for my conda environment.
Checking the environment path in Jupyter Notebook (sys.executable points to the correct Python interpreter).
Restarting the kernel and changing kernels, but the issue persists.

Activated Environment: I activated my conda environment in terminal with:
conda activate learning_jupyter


Check Python Executable: Running this in a code cell:

import sys
print(sys.executable)

Outputs:
/opt/anaconda3/envs/learning_jupyter/bin/python


Attempted to Install Packages: In the notebook, I ran:

!conda install sympy --yes

But received:
zsh:1: command not found: conda


Checked Installed Kernels: I ran the following in the terminal to ensure the kernel is set up:

jupyter kernelspec list

learning_jupyter appears in the list.

Reinstalled Jupyter: I reinstalled Jupyter within the environment:

conda install jupyter --force-reinstall


Kernel Configuration: I installed ipykernel:

conda install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name learning_jupyter --display-name "Python (learning_jupyter)"

Current Issues
Despite these steps, I am still unable to run any conda commands within Jupyter Notebook. When I try to execute !pip install sympy, it indicates that pip is also not found.
What could be causing the Jupyter Notebook to not recognize conda and pip commands?
Are there additional steps I should take to resolve this issue?
Is there a way to ensure that my Jupyter Notebook is fully utilizing my conda environment?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Please endeavor to use current best practices when trying to runpip install in an active .ipynb file. !pip install sympy should be %pip install sympy. That  magic variation was added in 2019 to insure the install occurs in the environment where the kernel is running. The exclamation point in conjunction with an install command doesn't do that and was often leading to issues. Your pip command may work fine here, but you'll have a better experience in all modern Jupyter if you adopt current approaches. ...

 See more about the modern %pip install command here. The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.

The big thing to keep in mind is that you should not be mixing and matching. You opted for the use of Anaconda/conda as your primary package manager and you need to stick with using it. %conda install conda-forge::sympy based on here and the magic conda install command at the link I gave you above. Sticking with conda will give you robust & portable environments, which is one of the main goals of project management. You should only ever use pip for packages that have no conda recipe. (I think in fact your experience is proving the point of why the magic versions were added.)

Did you install the Anaconda Distribution and use the Anaconda Navigator to launch Jupyter where you have been trying this?

@Wayne Hi, thanks for the insights! I did download the Anaconda distribution and have been using Anaconda Navigator to launch Jupyter. I followed your advice about using conda instead of pip and ran both %conda install sympy and %conda install conda-forge::sympy successfully. So that's great! However, when I try %ls, I get the error zsh:1: command not found: ls. Do you have any idea why this might be happening? !ls didn't work either

@Wayne also since I ran the magic conda commands and restarted my kernel, it won't reconnect

There's no magic ls command. %cd is one that has a magic equivalent. For ls, it is just ls with no symbol. I know it is a bit confusing which commands need which symbols and which commands are problematic if you use a symbol. As to your kernel not connecting: That sounds unrelated to using the magic conda command. You should restart everything and look for warnings & errors in the terminal if it continues.

@Wayne thank you again for your response. I contacted the anaconda developers via email and they instructed me to completely uninstall and reinstall the anaconda distribution. I created a new environment and connected it to the kernel, downloading the necessary packages. When I opened the Jupyter Notebook in the kernel, the %conda command worked, but typing ‘ls’ (without any symbol) gave me a “zsh: ls command not found” error. It seems like my shell isn’t interacting properly with Jupyter. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

@Wayne Actually, I figured out that the "zsh:1: command not found: ls" error in Jupyter Notebook indicated that my zsh shell couldn't find the ls command because it might not be in the PATH. The echo command worked since it's usually built-in. I verified my shell with !echo $SHELL, confirming it was zsh. I ran !/bin/ls, which worked. However, I want to avoid using the full path for ls. I've updated my .zshrc file with export PATH="/bin:$PATH" and reloaded it, but ls still requires the full path. Any suggestions?

Excellent sleuthing. This probably reveals quite a bit more of what is going on. I have been using zsh on my mac and ls works. This one stumps me. I'll keep my eyes open. At leas you have realized it works with the full path and it is a short path. (I wonder if you can set an alias?) Does it work directly in zsh?

Hi @Wayne, thanks! I'll split my response. I'm confused between your response and the Anaconda developer’s on running shell commands in Jupyter for ls. You mentioned no symbol for ls. Did I misunderstand? In Jupyter notebooks, shell commands typically need an exclamation mark (!). Were you referring to running it in the terminal? It works fine in zsh. Here’s what my terminal showed when I launched jupyter nb:
[W 2024-10-05 17:37:29.062 ServerApp] A `_jupyter_server_extension_points` function was not found in jupyter_lsp.```
It did launch though.

@Wayne I also saw this in terminal when I launched:
```Note: Debugging will proceed. Frozen modules may cause breakpoints to be missed. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off.
[I 2024-10-05 17:37:29.674 ServerApp] Skipped non-installed servers: python-language-server, dockerfile-language-server, etc.
The following commands work: `%conda`, `!pwd`, `!echo`, `import sys`. But `!whoami`, `ls`, or `!ls` fail. Anaconda dev suggested using `!ls` and checking permissions, but I can’t check since `!ls -l /bin/ls` doesn’t find `ls`. Running `!which ls` returns "ls is not found."

@Wayne I checked my PATH variable:
/Users/isabellamora/Downloads/apache-maven-3.8.5/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-18.0.1.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin$:PATH```
It’s missing `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, which could explain why `ls` isn’t recognized unless I use the full path (`!/bin/ls`). Do you still suggest I set an alias?

Are you able to add them to the PATH? That would solved things and you wouldn't need an alias.

@Wayne I tried adding /bin and /usr/bin to $PATH inside Jupyter via os.environ['PATH'] += ":/bin:/usr/bin". Checked $PATH in Jupyter, but it only showed limited directories. Ran !ls but still got "zsh:1: command not found: ls". Modified .bash_profile to include export PATH="$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin" below conda init, reloaded with source ~/.bash_profile, and restarted Jupyter, but no success. Also tried the zsh-specific path+=('/bin' '/usr/bin') command, no change. I won't make an alias because it's not imperative for me to get rid of the ls path, I just wish I could understand why

I don't understand what is going on either. I don't though think it is odd that adding the PATH isn't working because you have Anaconda involved and it is very isolated from the system environment. It was worth a try. If you really wanted to investigate, you could maybe make a new user on the computer and install the Anaconda Distribution there carefully. Making sure to do it as administrator and follow proper ways to make kernels in environments and connect them to Jupyter. Then see if that installation works better. Maybe read about current Macs & Anaconda first to be aware of gotchas.
